# Display main site tag wikis on hover in meta

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

Clicking a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) in a post on meta links to the stackoverflow tag, so we know it's referring to that tag not a tag that exists on meta (which is what I want and works fine).

Could the stackoverflow tag wiki be shown on hover as it would if hovered there?
This would save having to click it just to view the wiki excerpt. I guess this would apply to other SE main sites and their metas.

Comment: Do you mean clicking on tag in meta should be link to Meta question?

Comment: No, the clicking behaviour is fine, when I use `[tag:main-site-tag]` I mean to refer to the tag on the main site. I just want that tag's wiki to appear when I hover over it.

Comment: The tag wiki card would require a visual/textual indication that this is a main-site tag as compared to meta tag.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Sorry, not sure I follow. Are you saying having the wiki work for meta tags but not main tags is a good way of determining which site the tag refers to? To my mind my suggested change doesn't change the need (or not) to visually differentiate meta/main tags. If such a distinction is needed, maybe use the main site tag colour if it is a main site tag.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett You may already know this but I am re-iterating the following to avoid any confusion. In Meta Stack Overflow, a post body can contain references to SO and MSO tags. This is achieved if you use `[tag:so-tag]` or `[meta-tag:mso-tag]` respectively. Current behavior is that hover on MSO tags displays tag wiki but hover on SO tags shows only a tooltip. So there is a slight indication that a particular tag used inside a post is SO tag or MSO tag.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: I understand. I'd say that loosing the slight indication that a tag is meta or main shouldn't prevent this change; If an indication is needed beyond checking the link before clicking then some other indication could be used.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yes, I agree. As I said earlier any visual/textual indication on the wiki card may work.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Sorry, I understand now.